# Filtering Data in Multiple Tables with the Filter Function (Excel)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to return data from multiple tables based on a date. Each table has employee schedules with different tasks and I'd like to join these on a master output sheet that is dynamic with a formula.

```
=IF(A27=I27,FILTER(Employee 1,(Employee 1[Day]=D27)*(Employee 1[Name]=A27),"NA"),IF(A27=I28,FILTER(Employee 2,(Employee 2[Day]=D27)*(Employee 2[Name]=A27),"NA")
```

The above formula works if I toggle the employees name in a drop down list, but I'd like to have a "All" option that pulls in all of the employee names into the filter.

Something like this (the syntax is not correct):

```
=FILTER(Employee 1,Employee 1[Day]=D27),FILTER(Employee 2,(Employee 2[Day]=D27)))
```

Here is a photo of the summary I'm trying add a "all" option in the drop down.
[1][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpTFf.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Tough for me to visualize how this works w/out seeing some data. Why are there multiple tables? Is there an opportunity to create a single, narrow table with what you need for your master output, and then create your filters and formulas based on that single table?

Comment: My apologies, I added a screenshot of the summary I'm creating. There are multiple tabs where employees update their weekly/daily tasks which are then brought to a summary tab. We are using excel online which does not support Power Query so I can not merge tables. Looking for a formula workaround to pull all of the data into one table of sorts. If that helps explain it (hopefully). Appreciate you looking into.

Answer (score 0):

Very 1st of All, You are not allowed to use space in table names So, i changed your table names **from** Employee 1 and Employee 2 **To** Employee_1 and Employee_2
Now You can Use this formula to get the required result

```
=LET(name1,I27,name2,I28,tabname1,Employee_1[Name],tabname2,Employee_2[Name],daycheck1,Employee_1[Day]=D27,daycheck2,Employee_2[Day]=D27,x, FILTER(Employee_1,(daycheck1)*(tabname1=name1)), y, FILTER(Employee_2,(daycheck2)*(tabname2=name2)),rows1, COUNTIFS(tabname1,name1,Employee_1[Day],D27), rows2, COUNTIFS(tabname2,name2,Employee_2[Day],D27),myrows, SEQUENCE(rows1+rows2),cols,(IFERROR(COLUMNS(x),COLUMNS(y))),mycols, SEQUENCE(1,cols),IF(A27=I27,x,IF(A27=I28,y,IF(A27="All Employees",IF(myrows<=rows1, x, INDEX(y, myrows-rows1, mycols)),"NA"))))
```

Hope this works for you